# Handling Identifiers and literals in yacc/Bison

Tags: bison, yacc

For a class I have to write a compiler for Go. But I'm having some problems with handling identifiers. More specifically when they are used in arithmetic or logical operations. When working with just literals I can have rules like:

```
LOGICAL_OPERATION: BOOLLITERAL            
    | NOT LOGICAL_OPERATION                 
    | LPAREN LOGICAL_OPERATION RPAREN          
    | LOGICAL_OPERATION AND LOGICAL_OPERATION 
    | LOGICAL_OPERATION OR LOGICAL_OPERATION  
    ;

ARITHMETIC: ARITHMETIC PLUS ARITHMETIC
    | ARITHMETIC MIN ARITHMETIC       
    | ARITHMETIC MUL ARITHMETIC        
    | ARITHMETIC DIV ARITHMETIC        
    | DIGIT                            
    | LPAREN ARITHMETIC RPAREN 
    ;
```

This works, but when I try to add Identifiers to these operations I get reduce/reduce errors
When the next symbol is a semicolon, which is defined to end each statement, he doesn't know to which he needs to go.

Comment: Hi. What are the other rules in the grammar? If you only show two of them no one will be able to detect any conflict. Also, I assume identifiers are terminal tokens, right?

Comment: Reason a=true; and a=20; can be distinguished by using token returned but after adding id to productions of logical and arithmetic the grammar becomes ambiguous, because a=b; can be generated by either of the rules. You have rewrite such that a=b; should be generated once.